# Ubuntu + Vagrant + docker compose without using Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vagrant, docker-compose

Hy,

I have been using Vagrant + Docker on Windows PC for a while, with Virtualbox.
Since few weeks I have turned my mind toward Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and started to migrate my Vagrant stuff on my new hardware.

Some of Vagrants were using docker-compose on my old PC. Now, on Ubuntu, I want to use Docker and Docker-compose directly, without Virtualbox.
Certainly I could forget Vagrant and work directly with Docker compose, but I prefer to have every environnement monitored via Vagrant, to stay homogeneous.

I can't find information on how to use "docker compose" in this new context (Ubuntu 16 + Vagrant : prodiver = Docker and Provisionner = Docker compose).

Some link display the usage of "vagrant-docker-compose" plugin, but it dosen't work for me. I don't realy hunderstand why, but I think it's logical as I am using Docker directly on my machine, whitout VBox, and every example seems stating that your are using VBox.

Am I mistaking about the right way to solve my issue ?

Now my Vagrantfile looks like this (I tried other stuff...without any more success..):

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|

    docker.image="ubuntu:16.04"
    docker.compose=true

  end

    config.vm.provision :docker

    config.vm.provision :docker_compose, rebuild: true, yml: "/direct/docker-compose.yml", run: "always"

end
```

But the docker-compose.yml   isn't loaded....andd Vagrant says

> "he container started either never left the "stopped" state or very
>   quickly reverted to the "stopped" state. ..."

In fact : I don't understand where I must indicate the path to my docker-compose.yml   file....

Could you help me ?
Do you have a clue, or a link to a tuto ?
Can you enlight my mind saoul about the right way to solve it .... :[

Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

First, just to clarify that even though you are on Ubuntu and running Linux natively, the `docker` and `docker_compose` provisioners (I'm assuming from https://github.com/leighmcculloch/vagrant-docker-compose) will still run inside the Vagrant VM. It is not using the native Docker on your host.

Next, the `docker-compose.yml` file that it is referencing is from inside the Vagrant machine. Usually, this is the shared folder for the project at `/vagrant`. In this case, assuming the `docker-compose.yml` file lives next to the `Vagrantfile`, the `yml` path should be `/vagrant/docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Whatever I do Vagrant Seems not using the docker-compose.yml I specifie. I can even use a fool file name : Vagrant don't even complain....

Comment: thanks for the answer. Whatever I do Vagrant Seems not using the docker-compose.yml I specifie. I can even use a fool file name : Vagrant don't even complain.... Do you know how to use the  "docker.compose_configuration" Provider argument ? do you know if I can state le "yml" file at the provider level ? I don't understand the utility and the way to use provider param "compose" and "compose_configuration", there is absolutly no example on the Web.